# Why can't I run UNIT Tests in VSCode when I have 2 windows and 2 different projects open?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I am working on a project which has some existing unit tests and I have some tasking to start trying to make them work.

I did a course a couple weeks ago on Angular testing so I have a project I created from that with a bunch of beginner stuff to help me along.

I opened 2 instances of VSCode so that I can look between the 2 projects.

**ISSUE: ** Neither of the instances are actually running tests as far as I know unless I click on the run Unit test icon in the extension.

When I click on any of the run Unit tests in the project I need to do work in I get the following popup which prevents the running of the test(s). In the reference project I can run the unit tests. If I only have my project open I can run the unit tests.
[image]

SUGGESTIONS ON HOW TO FIX THIS?

Answer (score -1):

Well I resolved this.

I closed one editor and then reopened the project.

I really don't see how this application gets on the top 10 list.